# Set dynamic scheduling celerybeat

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I have `send_time` field in my Notification model. I want to send notification to all mobile clients at that time.

What i am doing right now is, I have created a task and scheduled it for every minute

tasks.py

```
@app.task(name='app.tasks.send_notification')
def send_notification():
   # here is logic to filter notification that fall inside that 1 minute time span 
   cron.push_notification()
```

settings.py

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'send-notification-every-1-minute': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.send_notification',
        'schedule': crontab(minute="*/1"),
    },
}
```

All things are working as expected.

**Question:**

is there any way to schedule task as per `send_time` field, so i don't have to schedule task for every minute.

*More specifically* i want to create a new instance of task as my Notification model get new entry and schedule it according to `send_time` field of that record.

> **Note:** i am using new integration of [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) with django not [django-celery](https://github.com/celery/django-celery) package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a task at specified date and time you can use `eta` attribute of `apply_async` while calling task as mentioned in [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown)

After creation of notification object you can call your task as

```
# here obj is your notification object, you can send extra information in kwargs
send_notification.apply_async(kwargs={'obj_id':obj.id}, eta=obj.send_time)
```

> Note: `send_time` should be `datetime`.

Comment: can i call same task for each notification? is it will work as separate thread?

Comment: @Satendra yes every time you will call this task it will work as a different instance.

Comment: Thanks @Parul  this is lot cleaner approach, i will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `PeriodicTask` and `CrontabSchedule` to schedule task that can be imported from `djcelery.models`.

So the code will be like:

```
from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask, CrontabSchedule
crontab, created = CrontabSchedule.objects.get_or_create(minute='*/1')
periodic_task_obj, created = PeriodicTask.objects.get_or_create(name='send_notification', task='send_notification', crontab=crontab, enabled=True)
```

Note: you have to write full path to the task like 'app.tasks.send_notification'

---

You can schedule the notification task in post_save of Notification Model like:

```
@post_save
def schedule_notification(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    instance is notification model object
    """
    # create crontab according to your notification object.
    # there are more options you can pass like day, week_day etc while creating Crontab object.
    crontab, created = CrontabSchedule.objects.get_or_create(minute=instance.send_time.minute, hour=instance.send_time.hour)
    periodic_task_obj, created = PeriodicTask.objects.get_or_create(name='send_notification', task='send_notification_{}'.format(instance.pk))
    periodic_task_obj.crontab = crontab
    periodic_task_obj.enabled = True
    # you can also pass kwargs to your task like this
    periodic_task_obj.kwargs = json.dumps({"notification_id": instance.pk})
    periodic_task_obj.save()
```

Comment: How can i identify for which notification object task is executing?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer i guess this will work, i will try and get back to you.

Comment: you are using `django-celery` and it is a old implementation of celery with django as per wiki, our product is using new celery http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html integration, so this will not work for me. i have already upvoted you for your answer thanks.

Comment: This could be helpful https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3493#issuecomment-304447118